# Why is the total number of possible symbol sequences not a suitable measure of information?

Tags: information-theory

In Ralph Hartley's 1928 paper, "Transmission of Information", he outlines a quantification of information as, $H = log(s^n)$.

H = information

s = number of primary symbols

n = number of selections made

In the beginning of the paper, he gives the intuitive suggestion that the total number of possible sequences given $s$ primary symbols and $n$ selections, $s^n$ may be used as a measure of information. However, he then goes on to suggest that this measure is not suitable and that information should be related to $n$ by a constant that is proportion to $s$. I cannot convince myself the validity of this argument, and I suspect the reason may be a practical one related to some aspect of engineering.

His justification is on page 5 of this document, I'm hoping someone could provide a more accessible explanation. http://www.uni-leipzig.de/~biophy09/Biophysik-Vorlesung_2009-2010_DATA/QUELLEN/LIT/A/B/3/Hartley_1928_transmission_of_information.pdf

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing/transmitting $n$ symbols $x_1,\ldots x_n$ will clearly take half the memory/time as that of $2n$ symbols $x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1},\ldots,x_{2n}.$ So information should grow linearly with $n$ while the original measure $s^n$ would grow exponentially.

As for the proportionality constant, if we number the symbols from 1 to $n$ the number of digits we require is $\lceil \log_b s \rceil$ where $b$ is the base of the representation, $b=2,$ for base 2 etc. We just omit the ceiling for simplicity and ease of manipulation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I still don't see what the implication of exponential growth is. If this is a good measure of information, which seems to be the most intuitive to me, then exponential growth is simply an intrinsic nature of information.

Comment: It's because Hartley developed the measure for information transmission and storage in mind. Otherwise any increasing function of $s^n$ would do. More importantly using the log gives an additivity property that $H(s^{n+n'})=H(s^n)+H(s^{n'})$ is exactly what's needed for those applications. For encryption, Renyi entropies can be more relevant see my answer to the following question http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40286/entropy-requirements-for-encryption/40292#40292 Otherwise your objection is more philosophical and as I indicated, reasonable.

Comment: Thank you, sounds like the choice was mainly a matter of convenience?

Comment: In a search to answer my own question, I found a wonderful mathematical proof that logarithm is the only possible way to satisfy some important properties. I won't type it here just because it is readily accessible online. One should search "mathematical foundations of information theory" by Khinchin and look at page 9 where he proves the uniqueness theorem which deals with a similar question as mine.

Comment: I am aware of this, but interpreted your question narrowly since you insisted on saying practical considerations didn't really matter for you, and asked only for the equidistributed case of Hartley.  my first paragraph of the answer and previous comment directly points  to $\log (s^n)$ but its nice you discovered this independently.